# md-switch/md-button inside md-card

Tags: angular-material, jquery-hover

I want to show md-switch and md-button inside md-card. I am able to show text inside md-card at correct place, but switch connected to that text is shown at some other position.

Card is shown to the user on hovering over some content.

DemoCode.html

```
<md-card>
        <md-card-header>
            <md-card-header-text>
                Sample 1
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>
        <md-card-content>
        </md-card-content>
        <md-card-actions>
                <md-switch ng-model="data.cb2" aria-label="Switch" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
                    {{ data.cb2 }}
                </md-switch>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question title and question content but here's an example of placing elements within a card - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/BzxkKd?editors=1010#0)

If this is not exactly what you need please explain further in an edit.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-card>
    <md-card-header layout="row">
      <md-card-header-text>
        Sample 1
      </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>
    <md-card-content>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <label>My Switch</label>
      <md-switch ng-model="data.cb2" aria-label="Switch" ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
        {{ data.cb2 }}
      </md-switch>
      <md-button class="md-raised">Hello</md-button>
    </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
</div>
```